# How to create srv/msgs fiels for Aruduino?

Tags: ros, arduino, catkin-make, ros-kinetic, catkin-make-isolated

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I've just started using ROS on the Arduino Uno and I have already run into the problem hat I don't know how to create my own srv/msgs files for the Arduino node.

In the normal ROS workspace you just have to create the srv/msgs files in the folders, add them to your CMakeList and then catkin_make. After that you can just include them into your node.

But how does it work for the Arduino node?

Best
Ottega

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/315478/how-to-create-srv/msgs-fiels-for-aruduino?/) by [Ottega](https://answers.ros.org/users/39993/ottega/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2019-02-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please refer to the following two tutorials (and the rest of the `rosserial` documentation & tutorials):

- [Adding Custom Messages(Generating Message Header File)](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Adding%20Custom%20Messages)
- [Generating Message Header File(Adding Other Messages)](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial/Tutorials/Adding%20Other%20Messages)

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-02-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2